# zend currency negative sign

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

Hello i am using **Zend_currency**

```
class Currency extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function currency($number, $locale = 'it_IT') {
        $currency = new Zend_Currency($locale);

        $number = $number + 0.00;//convert to float

        return $currency->toCurrency((float) $number);

    }
}
```

in a some view .phtml file

```
echo $this->currency($gimme_my_money);
```

and this is what i get

```
€ 19.373,25
-€ 116,07
```

how can i get it to print negative numbers like

```
€ -116,07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this formatting option is built into Zend_Currency.

What you can do, is move the currency symbol to the right side:

```
$this->view->total = new Zend_Currency(array('value' => $total, 'position' => Zend_Currency::RIGHT));
```

And then your currencies will be displayed with the currency symbol on the right:

```
 -19.373,25 €
```

If you want a custom formatting, with the negative sign after the symbol, (`€ -116,07`), you will have to write your own currency formatter or built on top of `Zend_Currency`

Answer (score 5):

Just overwrite the format option like this:

```
$cur = new Zend_Currency(array('format' => '¤ #,##0.00;¤ -#,##0.00'));
```

The trick is in the second part of the string (after the comma), I've checked it for Italian locale and the format string provided there is ¤ #,##0.00.

This is tested with ZF 1.11.7

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class My_View_Helper_Currency extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Format a numeric currency value and return it as a string
     *
     * @param int|float $value   any value that return true with is_numeric
     * @param array     $options additional options to pass to the currency
     *                           constructor
     * @param string    $locale  locale value
     *
     * @throws InvalidParameterException if the $value parameter is not numeric
     * @return string the formatted value
     */
    public function currency($value, $options = array(), $locale = null)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Numeric argument expected ' . gettype($value) . ' given'
            );
        }
        $options = array_merge($options, array('value' => $value));
        $currency = new Zend_Currency($options, $locale);
        return $currency->toString();
    }
}
```